# Django `manage.py test` ignores some tests

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

I have some django-based app. Inside this app I have `tests.py` file. Inside this file I have two test classes:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from django.test import TestCase, RequestFactory
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from translations import utils, views_ajax
from translations.models import Project
import json


def print_results(sentences):
    for sent in sentences:
        print "u\"" + sent + "\","


class TextSplitTest(TestCase):
    maxDiff = None

    def test_en_split(self):
        # some actions
        sentences, marked_text, count_num = utils.split_text(text_to_split, 'en')
        self.assertEqual(sentences, good_result)

    def test_fr_split(self):
        # some actions
        sentences, marked_text, count_num = utils.split_text(text_to_split, 'ru')
        self.assertEqual(sentences, good_result)

    def test_zh_split(self):
        # some actions
        sentences, marked_text, count_num = utils.split_text(text_to_split, 'zh')
        self.assertEqual(sentences, good_result)

    def test_es_split(self):
        # some actions
        sentences, marked_text, count_num = utils.split_text(text_to_split, 'es')
        # print_results(sentences)
        self.assertEqual(sentences, good_result)


class CreateProjectTest(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.factory = RequestFactory()
        self.user = User.objects.create_user(username='jacob', email='jacob@gmail.com', password='top_secret')

    def create_project(self):
        request = self.factory.post('/api/project-create/',
                                    data=json.dumps({'name': 4321, 'description': "ololo", 'type': "public"}),
                                    content_type='application/json')
        request.user = self.user
        response = views_ajax.create_project_ajax(request)

        all_user_projects = Project.objects.filter(manager=self.user)

        self.assertEqual(len(all_user_projects), 1)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)

    def add_text_to_project(self):
        project = Project.objects.get(manager=self.user, name='4321')
        data = json.dumps({"project":project.id,
                           "title":"French test",
                           "subject":1,
                           "sourceLang":7,
                           "targetLang":2,
                           "textBody":"Some text"})

        request = self.factory.post('/api/text/', data=data, content_type='application/json')
        request.user = self.user

        response = views_ajax.text_ajax(request)

        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

But when I'm trying to start tests, I'm getting:

```
# python manage.py test -v 2
...
test_basic_addition (entries.tests.SimpleTest) ... ok
test_en_split (translations.tests.TextSplitTest) ... ok
test_es_split (translations.tests.TextSplitTest) ... ok
test_fr_split (translations.tests.TextSplitTest) ... ok
test_ru_split (translations.tests.TextSplitTest) ... ok
test_zh_split (translations.tests.TextSplitTest) ... ok

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 6 tests in 0.224s

OK
```

And when I'm trying to start exact test class:

```
# python manage.py test translations.tests.CreateProjectTest -v 2
...
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 0 tests in 0.000s

OK
```

Why django ignores some tests? I've tried to google it out, but get nothing:(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The tests you want to run, should start with the word test:

```
def test_create_project(self)
```

etc...

https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#basic-example

> The three individual tests are defined with methods whose names start with the letters test. This naming convention informs the test runner about which methods represent tests.

Django docs: 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/testing/overview/#writing-tests

> When you run your tests, the default behavior of the test utility is to find all the test cases (that is, subclasses of unittest.TestCase) in any file whose name begins with test, automatically build a test suite out of those test cases, and run that suite.

Comment: oh, sh... Thank you very much!! But there's no such info in django doc. Or I'm too blind to see?)

Comment: @mega.venik It is in the django docs, but I can imagine, you missed it.  I updated my answer.

Comment: what a fail... Thanks again!